# ADODB query does not retrieve dates

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I am faced with some odd Excel behavior and I can not get my head around this.

I have a worksheet with a lot of data. For searching in this sheet, I use ADODB recordset and SQL query.

my query is quite simple:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [PIRNotes$] WHERE [PIR] = '" & WS & "'"
If rs.state = adStateOpen Then rs.Close
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
If cnn.state = adStateOpen Then cnn.Close
cnn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=" & _
        ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & ActiveWorkbook.Name
cnn.Open

rs.Open strSQL, cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

The issue I am having is that whatever is the value of WS and no matter how many records are found, each record always has rs.Fields(2) = Null.

rs.Fields(2) corresponds to the 3rd column of the worksheet which contains a string representing a date.
All the other columns are retrieved fine, the data there are also strings.

When I format the cells in the 3rd column as date and convert the contents to real dates, than the query runs without problems.

What could cause this behavior. I haven't the slightest idea where to begin solving this.

Comment: Could you show some of your data? Your code is working for me fine but I might not have the same data as you.

Comment: An additonal idea/Comment: Why don't you a Microsoft ACE OLEDB 12.0 connection string instead, see [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/).

Comment: After a lot of try and error, i now found that the issue is the formatting of my data on the worksheet. The data was formatted as a table. If I remove this (format the data as a range), the problem is gone.

Answer (score -1):

From Excel to Access!!

The following script runs from within Access.

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String
Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean
Dim intWorksheets As Integer

' Replace 3 with the number of worksheets to be imported
' from each EXCEL file
Dim strWorksheets(1 To 3) As String

' Replace 3 with the number of worksheets to be imported
' from each EXCEL file (this code assumes that each worksheet
' with the same name is being imported into a separate table
' for that specific worksheet name)
Dim strTables(1 To 3) As String

' Replace generic worksheet names with the real worksheet names;
' add / delete code lines so that there is one code line for
' each worksheet that is to be imported from each workbook file
strWorksheets(1) = "Sheet1"
'strWorksheets(2) = "csco"
'strWorksheets(3) = "sbux"

' Replace generic table names with the real table names;
' add / delete code lines so that there is one code line for
' each worksheet that is to be imported from each workbook file
strTables(1) = "TableName1"
strTables(2) = "TableName2"
strTables(3) = "TableName3"

' Change this next line to True if the first row in EXCEL worksheet
' has field names
blnHasFieldNames = True

' contains the EXCEL files
strPath = "C:\your_path_here\"

' Replace 3 with the number of worksheets to be imported
' from each EXCEL file
For intWorksheets = 1 To 1

      strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")
      Do While Len(strFile) > 0
            strPathFile = strPath & strFile
            DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, _
                  acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, strTables(intWorksheets), _
                  strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames, _
                  strWorksheets(intWorksheets) & "$"
            strFile = Dir()
      Loop

Next intWorksheets

End Sub
```

This will import the first sheet from several Excel files in a folder.  Take out the loop (`For intWorksheets = 1 To 1`) if you just want to import data from one Excel file.

Now, if you want to run the code from Excel and push data from Access, you can do it like this.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
On Error GoTo errH

    Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim intImportRow As Integer
    Dim sql As String
    Dim strFirstName, strLastName As String

    'CHANGE PATH TO DATABASE
    strPath = "C:\your_path_here\demo_db.accdb"

    'open the connection to the database
    If con.State <> 1 Then

        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strPath & ";"

        con.Open

    End If

    'delete all records first if checkbox checked
    If CheckBox1 Then
        con.Execute "delete from tbl_demo"
    End If

    'set first row with records to import
    'you could also just loop thru a range if you want.
    intImportRow = 3

    Do Until Cells(intImportRow, 4) = ""
        strFirstName = Cells(intImportRow, 4)
        strLastName = Cells(intImportRow, 5)
        strTheDate = Cells(intImportRow, 6)

        'insert row into database
        con.Execute "insert into tbl_demo (firstname, lastname, thedate) values ('" & strFirstName & "', '" & strLastName & "', '" & strTheDate & "')"

        intImportRow = intImportRow + 1
    Loop


    MsgBox "Done Exporting", vbInformation

    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing

Exit Sub

errH:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

I tested both code samples.  Both worked perfectly fine.  Make sure your data type in your Access table is date/time.

Comment: It is clear from both the OP's connection string and the question that they are fetching data from Excel.